# How do I evaluate the integral $\int \frac{1}{x^3 -1}dx$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

this is my first question here so I hope I did everything right. Still really new to LaTeX as well$$\int \frac{1}{x^3 -1}dx $$

I first used partial fractions to decompose this integral into two parts$$\int \frac{1}{3(x-1)}dx -\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{x+2}{x^2 + x + 1}dx$$

I definitely can solve the first part as $\frac{\ln(x-1)}{3}$ but I'm stuck with the second part as I don't know what to do since the denominator is not easily factor-able.

Thanks in advance to anybody taking the time to read this.

Edit: I do know that you can complete the square to make the integral prettier, but I don't know how to cancel the numerator or seperate it to relate the integral to $\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ to get some value of arctan(x) +c

Comment: Complete the square of the denominator, then proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess I should've clarified, as I mentioned below to Michael Hardy the 'proceeding' is the part I'm really stuck on, not how to factor x^2 + x + 1. I'm really poor at trig substitutions.

Comment: @tolan77 How did you use PFD to split up the original fraction? Can you show the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from that part,  you break up the integral into two parts:
$$\int \frac u {u^2 + 3/4}du+\int \frac {\frac 3 4} {u^2+\frac 3 4}$$

The first one you do as a simple $u$-substiution to get to $\frac 1 2 \ln (u^2 +\frac 3 4)$.

The second we factor out a $\frac 3 4$ and put the factored out part with the square, to get $$\frac 3 4 \int \frac 1 {(\frac {\sqrt 3} 2u)^2+1}du.$$
From there, use another u substution, setting $v=\frac {\sqrt 3} 2u$ so $du=\frac 2 {\sqrt 3}dv$, getting $$\frac 3 4 \cdot \frac 2 {\sqrt 3}\int \frac 1 {v^2+1}dv,$$  then you get your arctan.

Comment: O, DUH! Thanks a ton Alan, and Michael. I feel really silly now, but I appreciate you guys walking me through it. That second line here was really what was holding me up. I never thought to do something simple like that.

Comment: Not a problem,  these can be annoying if you haven't done them recently

Comment: Actually, in the second term, one should not factor $\frac34$ and one should use the change of variable $v=\frac2{\sqrt3}u$, not $v=\frac{\sqrt3}2u$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
x^2 + x + 1 = \left(x+\frac 1 2\right)^2 + \frac 3 4 = u^2 + \frac 3 4.
$$
The standard technique in algebra for reducing a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with a first-degree term to a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with *no* first-degree term to is **completing the square**.

Comment: Thanks for the really quick reply, I should've clarified more where my mental block really is. I thought about completing the square but I end up getting the integral (using your notation of u =(x+.5)) $$\int\frac{u+\frac{3}{4}}{u^2 +\frac{3}{4}}du$$ which I know must relate to arctan somehow since $\int\frac{1}{x^2 +1} = arctan(x) +c$ but that's where I feel at a loss, as it's been awhile since I took Calc 2 and my knowledge of trig substitutions are very poor.

Comment: Alan answers my question later below. So anyone stuck with a problem similar to mine read Alan's reply.

Comment: $w=u^2+\frac 3 4$ and then $\frac{dw}2 = u\,du$.  So you have $\int \frac{u\,du}{u^2+\frac 3 4} + \frac 3 4 \int \frac{du}{u^2+\frac 3 4}$.  The first one is handled by the substitution $w=u^2+\frac 3 4$; the second involves an arctangent.